# Grounding dc project to clean RF noise

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ground, rfid, interference

I'm doing a home automation arduino / RFID project and using a 12v DC switch mode power supply to power it.  This supply will be plugged in to a wall outlet. The project however will have some components inside the wall in a plastic project box.  It's an electronic dog door that goes from the inside to outside of the house through a wall. I live in an area with 'critters' that I don't want coming in the house.

When I power the project with battery everything works great and I get really good read distances from the rfid tags.  13 - 18cm depending on the antenna I use.

When I power it from the DC wall supply it barely reads at all. I practically have to rub the tag against the antenna and sometimes that doesn't even get a reading. I don't have a scope to see what's really happening in my power, but it seems pretty obvious that the switch mode type supply is noisy enough to mess up the 125khz rfid signals.

When I connect my circuit's GND to the 3rd prong ground on the wall socket my read ranges go back up almost as good as with the battery. Maybe 1 - 2cm less.

I have a 2-fold question:

Q1: My house was built in the USA in 2015 and has 3 prog wires everywhere. That should mean that all my ground wires are true ground, correct?  They shouldn't be connected to the AC neutral wire?  Are these are connected to earth?

Q2: My project will be installed in a wall in my house and there is a nearby outlet. Can I / is it safe to run a ground wire from that outlet to the project box (inside the wall) to ground my project circuit? OR is there another better way to properly ground the project.

[Update 2 - What I did] I don't feel that my question about safe grounding was answered. Everyone tried to solve a problem in my circuit, which I had already solved by grounding. I couldn't make power cables shorter but I did twist them as suggested. I added a grounding wire and attached it to some sheet metal that goes around the outside of the house. My read range is acceptable.

[Update 1] As requested here is a photo of the project on breadboards:

[image: Arduino RFID Project]

Vcc and Gnd from the power adaptor go to the black breadboard and are distributed to the Arduino Nano and the reader module. The black jumper wire on the left is the one I connect to wall ground to improve read distance. The orange/blue jumpers are RX/TX to the reader. The grey jumper cables go to 2 antenna tuning capacitors in the back. This is per the rfid reader board's manufacturers instructions. Green/Blue go to the antenna.  There is also a PIR motion sensor in the back but it isn't affecting this issue as removing it makes no difference.

Also to clarify something. I can completely remove the arduino and only connect power to the rfid reader board. Isolate that one component. By attaching an LED there I can see when it reads a tag. Same results are happening even when that board is used alone: battery power = good read ranges, dc supply = bad ranges or no reads at all, dc supply with gnd connected to house ground = good read ranges.

Comment: Have you tried different power supplies? Maybe the particular one you are using is of bad quality and hence causing the issue. If another good quality wall adapter works, you can call it a day. Usually SMPS ICs have frequency between 60 kHz to 120 kHz so there might be a possibility but a well made SMPS should work.

Comment: I've tried 4 or 5 different ones, different manufacturers, some that I bought specifically to power arduino projects, and some that I have around the house like 12v hard drive supplies.

Comment: One more suggestion - Try adding big filter cap - 16V 1000uF or so at the entry point of wall adapter and 0.1 uF decoupling capacitor as well close to the micro controller. If you are resourceful, try making a PI filter (2 caps 1 inductor). See if it helps.

Comment: Your talking on the DC side of the power adaptor?  I'm not an EE I'm a dangerous coder with a soldering iron, which is why I'm here asking. So I don't know where you mean that the cap should go - between what and what?  And "close to the micro controller" - everything is close to it.  It goes DC power plug and then 4 inches of wire and then the arduino.

Comment: Are you using proper arduino board? Or you made one yourself using Atmega328 IC on a PCB? Can you please share an image of the setup?

Comment: Photo added.  On the actual install I won't be using breadboards or jumper wires and will solder all the connections.

Comment: I think you are using that black DC jack to power it externally. You must be somehow getting two wires - VCC and GND out of it. Put a 16V or 25V 1000uF capacitor in parallel. Positive of cap to Vcc and Negative of cap to GND. or better yet, solder it to GND and VCC pins on the arduino board. Do the same with 0.1 uF cap. Do this with RFID module as well. Reggie has also pointed out some improvements. You might want to try that.

Comment: I wish there were still radio shacks around so I could drive 5 min and buy caps rather than having to order every component on Amazon. I'll try to get my hands on some. Yes that dc barrel jack has a black gnd and red vcc out the back that goes to the black breadboard. You can sorta see them in the photo.

Comment: If its differential mode interference, then a cap from "Positive of cap to Vcc and Negative of cap to GND" will help. You could also try a range of small value caps from Vcc to earth, and GND to earth, as close to the SMPSU as possible. One needs to find out which type of interference it is, then focus on the relevant solutions. Pay attention to the frequency response of the components you use, a capacitor turns into an inductor above certain frequencies!

Comment: You could also try shielding if you find it to be common mode interference. Put everything inside an earthed tin box. Be careful about heat and electrical insulation mind!

Comment: you may have both common mode CM and differential mode DM problems so require a combination of fixes, but it sounds like CM to me with the limited data you've given.

Comment: I'll try a capacitor and shortening and twisting my power wires. But as I said connecting gnd to house ground / earth fixes it. I don't have a scope to see exactly what's happening to the dc when I do different things. I had already tried a capacitor between +v and gnd and it had no effect, but it wasn't 1000uF it was 100uF - all I had handy.

Comment: Value of cap used depends on the frequency of interference. If you don't know,  then you need to try a range of values.  But looks like you have your solution,  if earthing it is practical. Good luck.

Comment: Right. Which is why I asked 2 questions about grounding it that no one has answered yet. Also I'm all for finding the source of the interference. But let's say that the cap reduces the interference by x %, how will that improve the read range compared to just grounding the circuit?  I need maximum read range for this application. And a battery gives that range and grounding it gives 95% of that read range.  Read my op again.  I'm trying to make sure that I ground it in a safe way.

Comment: Have you any pipes near by the unit? I did mention pipes in my response.

Comment: If the read range is satisfactory on both battery and earthed,  it still points to the SMPSU.  The earth is simply providing a return path back to the psu.  Because you can fix it with a good ground,  doesn't mean that's the most practical solution for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help and discussion everyone. I got it installed and grounding was very simple to do. Read range is decent but I'm still working on other aspects of the project. If I had more time, an oscilloscope, and it didn't take 3 days everytime I needed to buy a single capacitor - I'd try fixing my circuit instead of grounding it.  I'll eventually post about it on my blog and add a link here.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Looking at your photo, you need short cables, and on the main power cables, twist them with their respective 0v/earths, for good practice, even on a prototype.

For a test see if you can get your hands on a ferrite core that attenuates at your switching power supply's frequency around 125kHz. Try robbing one from an old switching power supply (smpsu) . They look like a donut shape bulge on the output or input to a SMPSU.

Place ferrites over all the output/or/ and input power supply cables,  including gnd, from the switch mode, then see if this helps.

If this does help then it's common mode interference coming from the switching power supply.

You can also try grabbing all the cables in your hand,  making sure they are insulated and **not electrically connected**,  and try and earth yourself.  It sounds silly but you are a capacitor to gnd for high frequency common mode signals! This will tell you it's common mode.

But mainly in response to your question,  I would strongly recommend grounding to metal pipework, It's probably safer, and legal, to earth to your pipework, rather than your house's electrical system .  All mettle pipework should be earthed.

You need to find the main path of interference,  these things can be very tricky to sort out and one can go round in circles,  but try the earthing to pipework,  with short multi core cable,  first.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the answer for the suggestion to ground to metal pipework.  I grounded to a metal stripping at ground level that goes around the bottom of the house. Since this is an electronic dog door project there is a hole in the wall that goes clear outside and without the dog door installed I have easy access to that metal strip.  I'll post a photo of it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the neutral is usually connected to the earth but ONLY at the fuse box (that connection is what keeps the neutral *neutral*). Running just the ground from an outlet is no big deal, I used to work for a company where they grounded their EMC test bench that way. It does sound like you've got a noisy power brick though, a bit of low esr capacitance on the board (a few uF of anything other than an electrolytic) and a shield around just the power supply should probably do it.

Comment: When I tested my circuit I was using a specific extension cord. Logistically I needed to get power to where I did the testing. Installed the power adaptor is directly in the wall. Technically I don't know if it's also dirty power directly from the wall. Someday I'll buy a scope and check these things out. But meanwhile the install is working as is. I could use a little more read range but working on that on the antenna end.  Thanks again.